# how can i pass one more parameter to php file using this code

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

here is jquery code

```
$(function(){
            var file_type = '';
            var btnUpload=$('#BackgroundimageUpload');
            var status=$('.status');
            new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
                action: "common_files/cover_image_change.php",
                //Name of the file input box
                name: 'uploadfile',
                onSubmit: function(file, ext){
                    file_type = ext;
                    status.html('uploading....');
                },
                onComplete: function(file, response){

                    //On completion clear the status
                    status.html('');
                    //Add uploaded file to list
                    if(response==="upload_error"){
                        alert("Error in upload");
                    } else{

                        var imgHtml = '<br/><br/><div><img src="uploads/'+response+'" style="width:100%; height:1004;" /></div>';

                        $("#timelineBackgroundUploading").html('');
                        $("#timelineBackgroundUploading").append(imgHtml);
                    }
                }
            });

        });
```

`

this is the above code and i want to pass one more parameter(id) to php file. how can i do that.

Comment: format your question

Comment: Don't try to put long code blocks in comments. Put it in the question so you can format it readably.

Comment: Can you give a link to the location of the `AjaxUpload` plugin you're using? I'm not able to find documentation of it with Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to pass like this using "params",

```
new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
            action: "common_files/cover_image_change.php",
            //Name of the file input box
            name: 'uploadfile',
            onSubmit: function(file, ext){
                this.setData({id: your_id});
                file_type = ext;
                status.html('uploading....');
            },
```

Comment: Hey ayyanar this is working absolutely fine... now tell me how can i pass 2 more parrameters ... i am doing like this this.setData({id: your_id, name: uname, gender: ugender}); ... btt this is not working

Comment: try using values in single quotes like this this.setData({id: your_id, name: 'uname', gender: 'ugender'});  if this also not working means repeat like this, this.setData({name: uname});this.setData({gender: ugender});...let me know whether its working or not

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this method

> action: "common_files/cover_image_change.php?id="+id,